# Java pre-instantiated array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

Attempting to pre-instantiate an array of JTextFields in a simple GUI that I am making. I am putting them into an array so that when I change states, I can cycle through them and clear the data with a simple for loop. The program is crashing after I have instantiated every object used in the window in the constructor. I have included the 2 lines where I declare the array and the 5 button objects. I am including how I am instantiating each of the TextFields as well. 
The code crashed upon calling my clear method, null pointer exceptions. upon closer inspection I see that my fields[0] through fields[4] are all null. I don't know why. 
tf1 through tf5 are not null

```java
//instantiation of fields t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 and fields array
private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5;
private JTextField[] fields  = {tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5};

//In the constructor
tf1 = new JTextField();

//clear method called after all objects are instantiated
private void clear() { for(JTextField f : fields) f.setText(""); }
```

expected fields[0] to have the same value of tf1, but is null;

Comment: Java is pass-by-value. It will not "link" to the variable. It will put whatever the variable is pointing to at array creation into the array, which is `null`. It will not remember the variable and update whenever the variable updates.

Comment: Why not `fields[0] = new JTextField()`?

Answer (score 3):

Observe the following code:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Main m = null;
    var ms = new Main[]{m};
    m = new Main();
    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(ms[0]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Main@5acf9800
null
```

Arrays don't keep the reference to the variable when they are created. Instead, they copy the value of the reference at that moment in time. Even if the value of the reference changes, the value within the array remains the same.

If you don't expect to be changing your array (at all), you can do something like the following:

```
//instantiation of fields t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 and fields array
private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5;
private JTextField[] fields;

//In the constructor
tf1 = new JTextField();
//instantiate the others as well if you'd like
fields = new JTextField[] {tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5};

//clear method called after all objects are instantiated
private void clear() { for(JTextField f : fields) f.setText(""); }
...
// anytime you update tf1 later, update fields[0].
// anytime you update tf2 later, update fields[1].
//     ...            ...            ...
```

Normally it'd be better to just keep variables, or just keep an array/collection. Managing one set of variables is annoying enough already; why make it harder on yourself by creating two sets?

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that to be completely honest, it doesn't make sense to keep more than one of the same instance variable. Only reason I was going to make an array (I thought) was to clear the text in the text fields faster, guess I just made it harder for myself

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an array of five `JTextField` objects, you can simply do the following...

```java
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fields[i] = new JTextField();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JTextField` references `tf1`, `tf2`, `tf3`, `tf4` and `tf5` are not initialized at the time you initialize your array.

So taking into account that Java is `pass-by-value`, your array gets initialized by `null` values.

When you assign `tf1` a value then it gets assigned a new object reference, thus is does not affect the previous object it was pointing to (if any).

Answer (score 0):

When you set the value for tf1, you have to re-add to the list. If you don't do that, only the variable tf1 will have a value, and not the Array item. How to fix, for example:

`tf1 =`**(some value)**`;
fields[0] = tf1;`

Answer (score 0):

*use an `unmodifiableList` instead of an array*

Your textFields tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5 will probably not change?

```
private List<JTextField> fields = Collections.unmodifiableList( Arrays.asList(
    tf1,
    tf2,
    tf3,
    tf4,
    tf5 ) );
```

the `clear()` function is then

```
private void clear() { fields.forEach( f -> f.setText( "" ) ); };
```